# Postgres order by array value

Tags: postgresql, datatable

In my table I've got a column named facebook with type text[] with array in it. For example:

```
{{total_count,26861},{comment_count,94},{comment_plugin_count,0},{share_count,26631},{reaction_count,136}}
```

I'm using my database with datatables and when I'm trying to sort my table by facebook I've got this:

[image]

And this is wrong. So I'm trying to get from this array only total_count as numeric value. Now I've got this:

```
regexp_matches(array_to_string(facebook, ' '), '(\d+).*')
```

But this returns arrays, for example:

[image]

So I've added ::numeric

```
regexp_matches(array_to_string(facebook, ' '), '(\d+).*')::numeric
```

but I'm getting an error:

> cannot cast type text[] to numeric

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: @lad2025 It was so simple... THANKS A LOT!!!

Comment: Sure, I posted it as answer :)

Answer (score 2):

> cannot cast type text[] to numeric

You need to cast to `numeric[]`:

```
regexp_matches(array_to_string(facebook, ' '), '(\d+).*')::numeric[]
```